# Keeping the session Open in JUnit/JPA/Hibernate/Struts and Spring integration test - No Session or session closed - LazyInitialization Exception

Tags: java, spring, jpa, junit, struts2

My application uses Struts2(mvc), Spring (Dependency Injection), JPA with Hibernate, JUnit along with struts2-junit plugin and struts2 spring plugin.

Here is my test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class CustomerSearchIntegrationTest extends StrutsSpringTestCase {

    @Test
    @Transactional
    public void testGetActionProxy() throws Exception {

        ActionProxy proxy;
        String result;

        ActionMapping mapping = getActionMapping("userInfo");
        assertNotNull(mapping);

        ..... // Some JUnit init code..

        ActionProxy proxy = getActionProxy("userInfo");
        UserInfo user = (UserInfo) proxy.getAction();
        result = proxy.execute();

        assertEquals("details", result);
        System.out.prinltn("Username:" + user.getFirstName());

    }
}
```

GetUserInfo

```
public class UserInfo extends ActionSupport {
     User user; // Entity
     UDetails details; // Entity

     public String getUserDetails() { //Action method
       user = userMgmt.getUser(usrId);
       if (user != null ) {
            for(UDetails det : user.getUDetails()) { // user.getUDetails() there is where exception gets thrown.
                if(det.getStreet().equals(street)){
                    details = det;
                    break;
                }
            }
       }
       ...
       ...
    }
}
```

User and UDetails are entities. UDetalis is `ManyToMany` with `User` and Lazily fetched. All entities are annotated.

UserMgmt

```
public class UserMgmt {
    public User getUser(String userId) {
        return userDao.getUser(userId);
    }
}
```

UserDAO

```
public class UserDAO extends AbstractJPAImpl{

    public User getUser(String userId) {
        User user = (User) getSession().get(User.class, userId);
        return user;
    }
}
```

AbstractJPAImpl

```
@Transactional
public abstract class AbstractJPAImpl {

    private EntityManager em;

    @PersistenceContext
    protected void setEntityManager(EntityManager em) {
        this.em = em;
    }

    @Transactional
    protected Session getSession() {
        return (Session) em.getDelegate();
    }

    ....
}
```

jpaContext.xml

```
<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
  // other config stuff
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
```

All configuration/context files are loading fine. Struts.xml, jpacontext.xml, beans.xml, etc. all are loaded.

But I get an exception:

```
failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.my.data.User.udetails, no session or session was closed

org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role:
```

at the following line:

```
 for(UDetails det : user.getUDetails())
```

Obviously, its trying to load `UDetails` lazily, then exception is throwing. 
However, this application works fine when deployed in a AppServer (WebSphere).

What could I be doing wrong? How do I keep session open?

**Update:** More info

I am using `OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter`. My web.xml below

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
        org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

**Update:**

This finally works, if I pass the parameter to `@PersistenceContext` annotation like below:

```
@PersistenceContext(type=PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED)
```

So I guess, the transaction is getting closed, but the entities are operable outside of transaction, because of the EXTENDED context type. However, I can't modify the code like above and leave it permanently. So I need to remove it.

So I guess, I have these options, but not sure if these are doable and how:

1. Get the persistence context from spring application context and pass the parameter. Not sure if this is relevant and possible.
2. Get the session/entity manager from application context and add another layer of transaction. That ways, the the session runs in two transactions. One is started from my testing code, and another one is in the existing code, which is automatically getting closed, while mine remains open until my test code completes execution.

For the 2nd one, I tried annotatting the method with `@Transactional`. But that did not work. Not sure why.

Any help?

**Update**

Looks like, struts-junit plugin does NOT load/read web.xml, which has the `OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter`. So it did not get loaded.

Any other work around or setup this filter?

Comment: Can you post full code of the test class or at least the class definition and any annotations applied at the class level?

Comment: @AlanHay updated my test class. Please check.

Comment: You are running an out of container test so In would not expect that Filter would fire. If everything is configured correctly I would however expect the outer transaction (on the test method) to remain active and allow the entity to remain 'attached'. I see you have seen the accepted answer here. Have you tried this solution? http://stackoverflow.com/a/19109838/1356423

Comment: @AlanHay If you read through the comments in the link you posted, you can see that, you will have upgrade Struts and all other dependencies, which I cannot afford to do. So I cannot use that solution. For me, even if I used, `@Transactional`, it did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it helps anyone, I couldn't get the @Transaction to work. But I put this:

```
 @PersistenceContext(type=PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED)
```

and it works now!

.....

Comment: Hi. Same issue here, but I am using Spring Data JPA. How to make it work with a JpaRepository ?